# M/F normal, determine whether there is an automorphism $\sigma\in Gal(M/F)$ with $\sigma(a)=a'$ and $\sigma(b)=b'$

Tags: galois-theory

Let $M$ be a normal extension of $F$. Suppose that $a, a'$ are roots of $min(F,a)$ and that $b,b'$ are roots of $min(F,b)$,and that $min(F,a)\neq min(F,b)$. Determine whether or not there is an automorphism $\sigma\in Gal(M/F)$ with $\sigma(a)=a'$ and $\sigma(b)=b'$

Comment: Do you mean for there to be another reference to $M$? It never gets used again.

Comment: Also similar to what @Dane pointed out, you don't define $K$ anywhere

Comment: @Dane, Thanks. I have edited the problem. There was a mistake.

Comment: Any other assumptions?

Comment: I just assume $min(F,a) \neq min(F,b)$.